# NeoVim: Move the cursor after running a command in :terminal

Tags: neovim

I have function to perform a git diff, after calling git diff I wish to emulate the following keypresses in the terminal window:

- `G` move to the end of the file
- `a` append
- `q<cr>` type q to quit the "terminal scrolling mode" then enter
- `gg` return to the top of the file

Code:

```
function GitDiff()
  terminal git diff --word-diff %
  normal Gaq<Esc>gg
endfunction
:nmap <leader>t :call GitDiff()<cr>
```

However the keypresses dont seem to be executed as expected. I wonder if it needs a delay to wait for the terminal command to finish executing?

Comment: Are you trying to quit the pager (such as `less`) launched by `git diff`? Why not run `git diff` using a function like `systemlist()` and write those contents to a scratch buffer instead? The terminal is quite tricky to automate, why do you think you need to use it here?

Comment: You probably need feedkeys or a term specific variant. Normal is a bit different

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Vim at least has `term_sendkeys()` but the doc says *"This requires for the job to be in the right state where it will do the right
thing when receiving the keys"* which I take it as this will send the keystrokes to the process running on the terminal and won't take normal-mode commands either...

Comment: @filbranden I tried to placing the contents of an external command to scratch buffer, and tried a host of hi coloring, but at the end of the day I couldnt get the output of git status to be colored. Whereas the terminal command colors it. I have since figured out I seem to be trying to get similar functionality as what magit does in emacs (or vimagit).

Comment: git status emits color escape sequences when it outputs to a terminal, but not when it outputs to a file. Try fugitive for vim, though.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble but one can add the color sequences  git -c color.status=always status | less

Comment: Right, but vim doesnt interpret them—so dont emit them when your putting it in vim

Answer (score 1):

Terminal buffer is not modifiable while the child process is running. You must send keys instead.

With Neovim you have to use `chansend()`. Assuming the terminal runs in the current buffer:

```
call chansend(&channel, "q\r")
```

Comment: This is almost there. call chansend(&channel, "q\r") quits correctly, then normal 7j moves the cursor down 7 lines, but normal 3w, or normal www, or normal 9l does not move the cursor to the right, only moves it down??? I dont understand why?